# StaleConfig error in sharded data cluster an error from cluster data placement change caused by version mismatch detected for db.collection_name"

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, sharding

Thanks for your help, we are getting StaleConfig errors in few cases, while inserting document in mongodb collection, which is Sharded.

I know we get StaleConfig issue during [chunk migration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions-sharded-clusters/#chunk-migrations) but in this error we are seeing caused by :: version mismatch detected for **db.collection_name**.

Your help is really appreciated.

**Version details**

**Spring Data Version:** 2.1.3.RELEASE

**Java Mongo Driver:** 3.12.5

**MongoServer Version:** 4.2.8

Performing only insert document to three different collection

```
org.springframework.data.mongodb.UncategorizedMongoDbException: 
Command failed with error 13388 (StaleConfig): 'Transaction 178d5e17-5cd1-459e-b425-eca33bf776a6:472 was aborted on statement 1 
due to: an error from cluster data placement change :: caused by :: Encountered error from <hostname>:<port> during a transaction 
:: caused by :: version mismatch detected for db.collection_name' on server "server_name:<port>". 
The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Transaction 178d5e17-5cd1-459e-b425-eca33bf776a6:472 
was aborted on statement 1 due to: an error from cluster data placement change :: 
caused by :: Encountered error from <hostname>:<port> during a transaction 
:: caused by :: version mismatch detected for db.collection_name", "code": 13388, 
"codeName": "StaleConfig", "ns": "db.collection_name", "vReceived": {"$timestamp": {"t": 382, "i": 3}}, 
"vReceivedEpoch": {"$oid": "5ec573a0ccf6d56864230435"}, "vWanted": {"$timestamp": {"t": 383, "i": 3}}, 
"vWantedEpoch": {"$oid": "5ec573a0ccf6d56864230435"}, "operationTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1596542628, "i": 36}}, 
"$clusterTime": {"clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1596542628, "i": 38}}, 
"signature": {"hash": {"$binary": "1fuZwXBpaoKtWb7NrH+tuSnpFYk=", "$type": "00"}, "keyId": {"$numberLong": "6823864140331745310"}}}, 
"errorLabels": ["TransientTransactionError"]}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: 
Command failed with error 13388 (StaleConfig): 'Transaction 178d5e17-5cd1-459e-b425-eca33bf776a6:472 was aborted on statement 1 
due to: an error from cluster data placement change :: caused by :: Encountered error 
from <hostname>:<port> during a transaction :: caused by :: version mismatch detected for db.collection_name' on server <server>:<port>.
```

Comment: Does the error go away when you retry the operation sequence?

Comment: Yes, I am doing retry, right now I am trying with limited number (5 times) of tries, and seeing this issue, having indefinite retry might cause performance issue. Is it ok to get StaleConfig error for Inserting document, any idea about caused by :: version mismatch detected for db.collection_name' I have doubt on this error message and what is the reason for version mismatch.

Comment: Use withTransaction, and add an mcve.

Comment: what is mcve and how to add that? I am running the query in Transaction (using Spring data Transaction), let me try with withTransaction as well.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=palemoon&q=mcve&ia=web

Comment: ok, got it. thanks.

Comment: Do you know the reason for  "caused by :: version mismatch detected" this is concerning me and it is coming very frequently. Retry will solve the problem, but is there any way to reduce StaleConfig issue with reason "version mismatch"

Comment: You need to provide a lot more details. What operations are you performing, what else is happening in the deployment, when the error happens, what kind of data is being operated on.

Comment: And versions of all software involved.

Comment: Versions:
Spring Data Version:  2.1.3.RELEASE
Java Mongo Driver: 3.12.5
MongoServer Version: 4.2.8

Performing only insert document to three different collection

Comment: Not seeing any issue with the deployment.

Comment: Is anyone going to describe what a mvce is, or are we going to play this game of guess the acronym.  The link to the duckduckgo was utterly useless and shows many different uses of the acronym. Is this intended to describe the concept of a minimally viable product (A.K.A., mvp)?

Answer (score 0):

With MongoDB in Sharded data cluster you might see these kind of exception, you can solve this simply retrying the transaction, MongoDB provide [callback API](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/) or you can have your own implementation of retry.

If you are using Spring-data and mongoTemplate from Spring and want to use withTransaction API, then call-back API will not work, because it retry for exception class "**MongoException**"
Snippet from **ClientSessionImpl** class.

```
public <T> T withTransaction(final TransactionBody<T> transactionBody, final TransactionOptions options) {
        notNull("transactionBody", transactionBody);
        long startTime = ClientSessionClock.INSTANCE.now();
        outer:
        while (true) {
            T retVal;
            try {
                startTransaction(options);
                retVal = transactionBody.execute();
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                if (transactionState == TransactionState.IN) {
                    abortTransaction();
                }
                if (e instanceof MongoException) {
                    if (((MongoException) e).hasErrorLabel(TRANSIENT_TRANSACTION_ERROR_LABEL)
                            && ClientSessionClock.INSTANCE.now() - startTime < MAX_RETRY_TIME_LIMIT_MS) {
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                throw e;
            }
            if (transactionState == TransactionState.IN) {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        commitTransaction();
                        break;
                    } catch (MongoException e) {
                        unpinServerAddressOnError(e);
                        if (ClientSessionClock.INSTANCE.now() - startTime < MAX_RETRY_TIME_LIMIT_MS) {
                            applyMajorityWriteConcernToTransactionOptions();

                            if (!(e instanceof MongoExecutionTimeoutException)
                                    && e.hasErrorLabel(UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION_COMMIT_RESULT_LABEL)) {
                                continue;
                            } else if (e.hasErrorLabel(TRANSIENT_TRANSACTION_ERROR_LABEL)) {
                                continue outer;
                            }
                        }
                        throw e;
                    }
                }
            }
            return retVal;
        }
    }
```

Since mongoTemplate with Spring-data and with **Transactional** annotation wrap the Transaction related exception in "**MongoTransactionException**" hence **withTransaction** api with mongoTemplate doesn't do retry, because it looks for "**MongoException**" class.

So if you want to have retry using spring-data with mongoTemplate, then you can use Retryable framework as below.

```
@Transactional(value = "mongoTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Retryable(value = {MongoCommandException.class, MongoException.class}, exclude = {MongoTransactionException.class, UncategorizedMongoDbException.class},
        backoff = @Backoff(delay = 10), maxAttempts = 10)
public void performingTransactionaOperations(DocumentBean1 document1, DocumentBean2 document2, DocumentBean3 document3){
    try {
        mongoTemplate.insert(document1);
        mongoTemplate.insert(document2);
        mongoTemplate.insert(document3);
        
    }catch (MongoTransactionException | UncategorizedMongoDbException ex){
        MongoException mongoException = null;
        if(ex.getCause() instanceof MongoException) {
            mongoException = (MongoException) ex.getCause();
        }else if(ex.getCause() instanceof MongoCommandException){
            mongoException = (MongoCommandException) ex.getCause();
        }
        if(mongoException!=null && mongoException.hasErrorLabel(MongoException.TRANSIENT_TRANSACTION_ERROR_LABEL)) {
            System.out.println("TransientTransactionError aborting transaction and retrying ...");
            throw mongoException;
        }else if(mongoException!=null &&  mongoException.hasErrorLabel(MongoException.UNKNOWN_TRANSACTION_COMMIT_RESULT_LABEL)){
            log.debug("UnknownTransactionCommitResult, retrying commit operation ...");
            throw mongoException;
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: If providing Java code examples, please include the imports.